# How to create common module that can run in all frameworks like angularjs, angular 2+, react

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, npm, module

I want to create a middleware package that can handle HTTP request and response.
I want to make it in such a way that it can be usable in angularjs, or angular2+, react.

I tried this by creating an npm module. This npm package is working perfectly fine in angular2+ projects but not working in angularjs project because I have used some other npm package in our package and using the method of that npm package by requiring(i. e. var Core = require(./somejs file)) those package and require syntax gives me an error in angularjs project.

I have uses XMLHttpRequest for making HTTP request.

Comment: As long as your NPM modules doesn't depend on them, you should be fine.  React & Angular are only really View engines at the core.

Comment: If data changes, you won't see it in angularjs because you need to run the digest cycle

Comment: What should be the best approach to create such module that can be usable in angularjs, angular2+ and react framework?